# Android setprop: failed to set property

Tags: android

I found the following command in the Firebase docs:

```
adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.securitycentery
```

This will enable Firebase debug events for my app, and they will get shown in the Debug View of Firebase console.

And this is a nice way to debug an app, so I thought I'd use the same tool to add debug functionality to my app. I decided to `setprop` something and then access this property from my app.

However when I do `setprop`, it fails:

```
adb shell setprop someprop xyz


setprop: failed to set property 'someprop' to 'xyz'
```

Why is that? Do I have to declare my properties to be able to set them? If so, how is this done?

My phone is not rooted. The Firebase `setprop` command works without any extra setup. I want the same for my properties.

Answer (score 1):

There are only small subset of prefixes that can be set without rooting device. I don't remember exactly all list, but "debug.someprop" should work.